# Regex for name type

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on regex with the following conditions:

1. Must contain from 1 to 63 alphanumeric characters or hyphens.
2. First character must be a letter.
3. Cannot end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive hyphens.

I am able to get the regex like: 
   `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]$`

But it fails on the length constraint as well as allows patterns like "a-". How can I meet the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your requirements as:

```
^(?=.{1,63}$)(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

### Demo

Here is a brief explanation of what each part of the above regex does:

```
^              from the start of the match
(?=.{1,63}$)   assert that the string is between 1 63 characters
(?!.*--)       assert that two hyphens do not appear together anywhere
[a-zA-Z]       first character is a letter (mandatory in all matches)
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

The final portion says to match a final character which is alphanumeric, but not dash, possibly preceded by alphanumeric characters or dash.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me what that "\" before the "-" stands for ?

Comment: @FellowBeginner I am escaping the dash inside the character class. You actually don't have to do that, since I put it at the end, but it's considered best practice to do so.

Comment: Sir, could you tell me why you wouldn't use `(?!\-\-)` instead of `(?!.*--)`?? +1 from me

Comment: Because `(?!--)` just says to assert that two dashes don't appear from that position.  We want to make sure that two dashes don't appear _anywhere_ in the string.

Answer (score 2):

My take on this would be:

```
^[A-Za-z](?!.*?--)[A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,62}(?<!-)$
```

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/SQYUjn/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Matches the start of the string.
- `[A-Za-z]` - Matches the first letter.
- `(?!.*?--)` - Ensures that there are no two consecutive hyphens in the rest of the string.
- `[A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,62}` - Matches the remaining alphanumeric and hyphen characters.
- `(?<!-)` - Ensures that the string doesn't end with a hyphen.
- `$` - Matches the end of the string.